# php import csv first row table header

Tags: php, csv

I have a csv file that I will import on a php page. But he must set the first row as a table header (th).
I use this script but for now I have only table rows (tr)

```
<?php
                echo "
                <table class='table table-striped table-hover'>\n\n";
                $f = fopen("myfile.csv", "r");
                while (($line = fgetcsv($f)) !== false) {
                echo "<tr>";
                foreach ($line as $cell) {
                echo "<td>" . htmlspecialchars($cell) . "</td>";
                }
                echo "</tr>\n";
                }
                fclose($f);
                echo "\n
                </table>
            ";?>
```

Can someone help me with this code to set the first row as header and the rest as tr.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
$flag = true;
while(..) {
    if($flag) { 
        // Proceed header here
        $flag = false; 
        continue; 
    }
    // the rest rows
}
```

**Updated**

```
echo "<table class='table table-striped table-hover'>\n\n";
$f = fopen("myfile.csv", "r");
$flag = true;
while (($line = fgetcsv($f)) !== false) {
    echo "<tr>";
    if($flag) { 
        // Proceed header here
        foreach ($line as $cell) {
            echo "<th>" . htmlspecialchars($cell) . "</th>";
        }
        echo "</tr>\n";
        $flag = false; 
        continue; 
    }

    foreach ($line as $cell) {
        echo "<td>" . htmlspecialchars($cell) . "</td>";
    }
    echo "</tr>\n";
}
fclose($f);
echo "\n </table>";
```

Comment: <?php
                echo "
                <table class='table table-striped table-hover'>\n\n";
                $f = fopen("myfile.csv", "r");
                while (($line = fgetcsv($f)) !== false) {
                echo "<tr>";
                foreach ($line as $cell) {
                echo "<td>" . htmlspecialchars($cell) . "</td>";
                }
                echo "</tr>\n";
                }
                fclose($f);
                echo "\n
                </table>
            ";?>

Comment: '<tbody><tr><th>Summary</th><th>Status</th><th>Priority</th><th>Assignee</th><th>Created</th><th>Updated</th></tr>
<tr><td></td><td>2</td></tr>

 </tbody>'

Comment: New question placed :-)